# DBeaver connection via SSH tunnel

Tags: mariadb, aws, amazon-ec2, dbeaver, ssh

Using DBeaver, I'm trying to connect to my AWS ec2 instance where I've installed a MariaDB database.

I've created a new connection as:

- Connection: AWS / Maria DB
- Server Host: localhost   (because I'm using ssh to connect)
- Database, Username and Password: the right ones
- Port: 3306

SSH tunnel on the connection:

- Use SSH Tunnel: checked
- Host/IP, Port and User: as suggested by the AWS documentation
- Auth: Public Key
- Private key: file .pem (the one I'm also using to connect via ssh from command line)

The connection works great at the beginning.
After some minutes of inactivity if I open a table the connection stucks and I need to invalidate/reconnect to fetch the data.
This process sometimes is done by DBeaver, after 15 seconds of not fetching anything, but sometimes even if I wait 2 minutes it keeps running but fetching nothing.

Is there something I'm missing in my configuration?
Or some configuration on the server maybe.. I don't know..

Have you ever had this problem?

Comment: there is in the connection settings a keep alive in dbeaver and the my.conf also has also one

Comment: @nbk dbeaver ssh keep-alive is set to 0, tunnel connection timeout to 10000. On the ec2 instance in /etc/my.cnf there is nothing useful..

Comment: Could it be the SSH Tunnel is "sleeping" during inactivity?

Comment: @J.D. it could be, but I don't know how to prevent it from going to sleep or how to wake it up..